# Building a data layer using Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Do you know of any resources that describe building a data access layer using Spring's JdbcTemplate classes? I'm looking for something beyond the basics described in the Spring framework documentation.

Comment: Is the Spring documentation lacking something you require in your data access layer? If so, would you be able to offer an example of this shortcoming to help me better understand your question?

Comment: I'd like to see an example of how all of the Jdbc-related classes are put together to design a DAL. I have rolled my own primitive DAL, but would like to see a more comprehensive implementation.

Comment: Please keep us updated on what you find - I'm interested in this subject as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not the online docs, perhaps books will help.  "Spring in Action", "Pro Spring", "Spring Recipes" - take your pick.  I'm not sure how much detail you're looking for, though.  I fear that you'll be disappointed.

Comment: Thanks. Spring in Action has little beyond the 'best practices' section of the Spring docs. I'll look into the other books.

Comment: The 2 apress books you mention have a lot of good code that give examples of using SQLFunction, SQLUpdate, MappingSqlQuery, etc. This is more or less what I was looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of exactly what it is you are looking for, but I basically create a DAO class that has a SimpleJDBCTemplate as a property. It is set via dependency injection. The public methods of the DAO abstract the interaction with the SimpleJDBCTemplate.